# How do I resync my git repository with heroku where a heroku add-on has changed code on the heroku version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have deployed a Rails 3.2 site to Heroku which I wanted to submit to an external party (QuickBooks) for assessment. I used the tinfoil add-on to security test my site. It gave me the all clear - but then I found it has injected code onto my site i.e. things like:

| VBScript:tinfoil_xss_in_element_attribute=6f8246002c1c5967ffc5e0ec80f2d7b59a60b1e3'| overwrite key menu items in my masthead.

Go figure.

Anyhow, I have this in train with Heroku support but they aren't rushing back just now so I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone has been here before and found an answer.

I've rolled back to my first version but its still there so rolling forward again won't fix it. 
I'm not a Git guru - I can't find a Git push option that doesn't say "Everything-up-to-date".
What is my best way to rectify or will I have to save the db, demolish the app and rebuild next door?

Comment: Simply removing the addon with `heroku addon:remove` should get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks. When I calmed down, I found that GitHub was working as it should have been - tinfoil had actually only overwritten data (an account name that then populated menus etc.) not static content - so removing the addon and correcting the data worked fine.